# Custom random number generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm new to creating objects in JavaScript. I need to make a random number generator that doesn't repeat itself too often (I have not tried to implement that part in the code snippet below). How can I access `n` from function `RNG(n)` in `RNG.prototype.rand`? It's showing up as unreachable in my editor the way I have it written now. I'm also not sure if I should return from `RNG` or `RNG...rand()`:

```
function RNG(n) {
  this.n = n;  
}

RNG.prototype.rand = function() {
  var arr = [];
  var num = Math.floor(Math.rand()*n);

  //keep array of generated numbers
  if(num < arr[0]){
    arr.unshift(num);
  }
  else{
    arr.push(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: [`.n` is a property, but you use it like a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.n` is an instance property which created when you instantiate the instance:

```
function RNG(n) {
    this.n = n;  
}

var rng = new RNG(5);
console.log(rng.n); // 5
```

`RNG.prototype.rand` is an instance method. Within the method, if you want to reference the instance itself, you should use `this` as well.

```
function RNG(n) {
    this.n = n;  
}
RNG.prototype.method = function() {
    console.log(this.n);
};

var rng = new RNG(7);
rng.method(); // 7, within this method `this` is `rng`, so `this.n` gives you `rng.n`
```

If you try this code:

```
function RNG(n) {
    this.n = n;  
}
RNG.prototype.method = function() {
    var n = 3;
    console.log(n, this.n);
};

var rng = new RNG(7);
rng.method(); // 3, 7
```

Here without `this.`, `n` is actually trying to get a variable defined with `var n = 3;`. It has nothing to do with the instance property `rng.n`

And finally, if you don't define `n`:

```
function RNG(n) {
    this.n = n;  
}
RNG.prototype.method = function() {
    console.log(n);
};

var rng = new RNG(7);
rng.method(); // ReferenceError: n is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code you want `this.n` rather than `n`. Unlike some languages, 'this' is not assumed.

To answer your other question, the way you have it set here, you want to return from `rand`, though to be frank I don't see why you wouldn't just take `n` as a param to `rand()` instead of making a stateful object w/ a constructor and whatnot.

Comment: I'm working on an exercise on code wars and this is how it is given. If you can think of any benefits this method might yield, I would be happy to hear them. Does "this" in Jscript work the same as it does in Java?

Comment: Generally,if you have more data you want to share across a number of functions, you'd use this pattern.  `this` is similar to the Java version, but I would not say it works exactly the same, no.